# Higher kinded types vs generics

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I'm reading about higher kinded types in Scala and I can't wrap my head around the use of the underscore.

For example:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}

val listFunctor = new Functor[List] {
  override def map[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: A => B) = fa.map(f)
}

listFunctor.map(List(1,2,3))(_ + 3)
```

If I use a parametrised type A in the trait, I get the same result:

```
trait Functor2[F[A]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B) : F[B]
}

val listFunctor2 = new Functor2[List] {
  override def map[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: A => B) = fa.map(f)
}

listFunctor2.map(List(1,2,3))(_ + 3)
```

Is there a significant difference between the two examples?

Comment: In your second example your `A` comes from `map[A, B]`.  The one defined in `F[A]` is a different one. It's just a placeholder. And it can't be used outside of the signature.

In general, a higher-kinded type is just a type which takes another type as an argument. Syntax isn't so important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between those two ways to express the fact that `Functor2` is parametrized over a type constructor. If you notice, in the latter case, `A` is just a placeholder, as it hasn't been declared elsewhere.

I generally prefer to use the `F[_]` syntax as it clarifies we want a type constructor and we don't have accidental overlapping in naming between the placeholder and types as referred within the class: in the latter case, even though they *happen* to refer to the same type parameter, there is no enforced constraint between the `A` in the constructor signature and the `A` in the `map` method signature, and this can also lead to some confusion regarding the nature of the two `A` and how they are related to each other.